# How to fix deprecation Relation#first with finder options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In console when I am running the line "Zip.code(74738).users.count" I am receiving the following error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#first with finder options is deprecated. Please build a scope and then call #first on it instead. (called from code at /Users/lexi87/DATING/app/models/zip.rb:6)
  Zip Load (12.6ms)  SELECT `zips`.* FROM `zips` WHERE `zips`.`code` = 30052 ORDER BY `zips`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

I have tried a few things but still continue to get the warning. Here's the original code it's pointing to:

```
  def self.code(code)
    first(:conditions => {:code => code})
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Rails 4, use [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)

```
def self.code(code)
  find_by(code: code)
end
```

With Rails 3, use `where(...).first` instead of the dynamic finders `find_by_attr` (do not perform well)

```
def self.code(code)
  where(code: code).first
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def self.code(code)
  where(:code => code).first
end
```

This should have the same behavior: one ActiveRecord object if it's found, or nil if it's not.